# Migration rollback doesn't work properly in Phalcon 2.0.9

Tags: php, database-migration, phalcon

I have a MySQL database with some data, in a production environment. My first migration is:

```
class SampleMigration_101 extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        self::$_connection->execute("ALTER TABLE `phalcon`.`sample` DROP INDEX `login`;");
    }
    public function down() {
        self::$_connection->execute("ALTER TABLE `phalcon`.`sample` ADD INDEX `login` (`login`)");
    }
}
```

Then, I create another migration for the same table with something like this:

```
class SampleMigration_102 extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        self::$_connection->execute("ALTER TABLE `phalcon`.`sample` ADD INDEX `login` (`login`)");
    }
    public function down() {
        self::$_connection->execute("ALTER TABLE `phalcon`.`sample` DROP INDEX `login`;");
    }
}
```

But if I want to rollback to 101 (>phalcon migration run --version=1.0.1), I lose my sample table.

- Why do I need to always call a morph function?
- Why is the table deleted if I don't have a morph function?
- Why does each migration need to have a lot of information?